# Sonar - branch coverage issue because of expected in JUnit4?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have a JUnit 4 test, which checks if an exception is thrown by the code I'm testing. The test looks as follows:

```
@Test(expected = AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.class)
    public void getChannelKeysThrowsAmqpRejectAndDontRequeueExceptionIfProcessIdIsMissing() {
    processNameBasedRouter.getChannelKeys(new GenericMessage<Object>(new Machine()));
}
```

In SonarQube an issue was raised because a branch is not covered. In my opinion this branch is covered and if I run the tests in IntelliJ I get 100% coverage. I assume it is because of the expected exception check in JUnit4 or is there another reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Is that test in the same module as the class under test ? The fact that you use the `expected` in your test should have nothing to do with the coverage issue described.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The test class is in the same package in test-folder as the class under test in src-folder. So the answer is yes, it's in the same module.
I agree, it should have nothing to do with the coverage issue, but everything else seems to be same like in other test classes

Comment: Can you provide the code of the GenericMessage class ? it is hard to help you without full context here.

Comment: The GenericMessage class is the one from Spring (package org.springframework.integration.message)